# Drupal 7 php if statement

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to create a simple php if statement that goes something like this:

```
<?php   if ($node->type == 'sales_team_page') {
'some html code goes here';
   }
?>
```

This is not working though. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Define "not working".  Is the condition for the if statement being met? Does `$node->type` ever == `'sales_team_page'`?  If so, what are you trying to do with your `'some html code'`?  If you're trying to output HTML code, you need to use PHP's `echo`, as in: `echo 'some html code goes here';`  More information would be helpful :)

Comment: I am trying to output html code.  I have tried it with echo though.  Everything I have tried does not output the html code.

Comment: What file are you placing this code in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output in Drupal is handled by the theme layer. Depending on what you're trying to ouput, you typically pass an array to a theme_function. For instance, if you want to output a link, you use `theme_link()`. api.drupal.org comes in very handy. An intro to the theme layer and a list of theme_functions lives here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--theme.api.php/group/themeable/7.

It also seems possible that your condition isn't being met.